# How to subset a table that contains blank entries

Tags: r

I have a table that contains 5 columns and >100k rows

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
foo     bar
foo1    bar1    this1  that1    other1
foo2    bar2           that2    other2
```

I would like to read in this table so that the blanks are either

1. read in as NA, or
2. those rows are ignored

I tried `a=read.table("a.txt",header=F,sep='\t',na.strings=c("NA","NULL"))`, but found that `NA` only comes up in integer columns, not strings. I have been trying to subset the resultant table to remove the column with blanks but have not succeeded yet.

I have tried:

```
subset(a,a$V4!= ' ')
subset(a,a$V4!= '\t')
subset(a,a$V4!= '\w')
subset(a,a$V4!= '\s')
subset(a,a$V4==NULL)
subset(a,a$V4==is.na)
```

all to no avail.

I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Can you show sample data ?

Comment: try `na.strings = c("", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @adibender said, you probably have some unknown number of whitespace characters in those blank fields. Including `c('', ' ')` may solve it for some fields, but if the number of whitespace characters is different, you'll still have some blanks.

R does not use regex in comparisons like you have above in `subset(a,a$V4!= '\s')`. You can use `grepl` to do regex comparisons and get back a logical answer, e.g. `a[!grepl('[[:space:]]', a$V4), ]` (return the rows of `a` where whitespace characters were not found in `a$V4`).

If you want to remove the whitespace and replace with NA (assuming no whitespace is valid), I would probably use `gsub` or `str_trim` from `stringr` and then `ifelse(a$V4 == '', NA, a$V4)` change from empty strings to `NA`.